# Vite + SvelteKit + MariaDB: importing script with databse connection throws weird errors

Tags: database, mariadb, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I am trying to build simple app using Vite + SvelteKit that will connect to a server with MariaDB database. I tried many options, but nothing worked. When I tried to do connection like this:

Here is script I use for connection to database:

```js
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';

const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "admin",
  password: "givdb",
  database: "givdb",
});

console.log('Connected to MariaDB');

export default connection;
```

Here is main svelte page.

```html
<script>
  import connection from '../db';
  
  async function fetchData() {
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM User');
    console.log(rows[0].Email,"(This was fetched from database)");
  }

  fetchData();
</script>

<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>
```

This Code results in successful Fetching of Data from database as shown here:

```
> vite dev "--" "--open"



  VITE v4.1.1  ready in 412 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
Connected to MariaDB
lonzikormos@gmail.com (This was fetched from database)
17:22:43 [vite-plugin-svelte] ssr compile done.
package         files     time     avg
giv-sveltekit       3   50.7ms  16.9ms
```

But app shows just replaces whole app with Error:

```
manifest.js:14 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at node_modules/.pnpm/safer-buffer@2.1.2/node_modules/safer-buffer/safer.js (safer.js:25:33)
    at __require2 (chunk-7FP5O474.js?v=72350a59:10:50)
    at node_modules/.pnpm/iconv-lite@0.6.3/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.js (index.js:3:14)
    at __require2 (chunk-7FP5O474.js?v=72350a59:10:50)
    at node_modules/.pnpm/mysql2@3.1.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/parsers/string.js (string.js:3:15)
    at __require2 (chunk-7FP5O474.js?v=72350a59:10:50)
    at node_modules/.pnpm/mysql2@3.1.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js (packet.js:11:22)
    at __require2 (chunk-7FP5O474.js?v=72350a59:10:50)
    at node_modules/.pnpm/mysql2@3.1.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js (packet_parser.js:3:16)
    at __require2 (chunk-7FP5O474.js?v=72350a59:10:50)
```

When I comment the section that tries to fetch Data, the Error preserves, but when I comment the fetching part also with the import Line from +page.svelte of my first attempt (import connection from '../db';),error dissapears but then I cannot possibly fetch Data from database...

**So the problem roots in importing database connection script. But I don't know how to resolve this. PLS help I'm desperate.**

Comment: Do **not** screenshot code or console output. Include it as formatted  text in the question.

Comment: Thx a lot for help! I tried to make it better. Sorry for inconvenience. Still trying to figure out the bug tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql2`, and possibly some dependencies, are Node libraries that are not browser compatible. By placing the respective code in the Svelte file it will run in the browser and consequently not work.

When using SvelteKit you should move such code to a server [`load` function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#page-data), this is ensured my putting it in a `+page.server.ts`/`js` file. The data is then fetched by the server and can be passed as the `data` property to the page. See the documentation for examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I see, i gotta read more documentation.